# The Meaning of ちょっと前に

Tags: translation, time

I'm not sure I completely understand the usage of ちょっと前に in this context:

​一年**ちょっと前に**結婚しました.

Does this mean:

- "I got married around a year ago" (implies more or less than a year)
- "I got married a little over a year ago" (implies unspecified short amount of time MORE than exactly 1 year ago)
- "I got married roughly a little over year ago" (implies uncertain time MORE than exactly one year ago)

My original intention was to say:
**"I got married a little over a year ago."**

Can someone explain to me which is the most accurate translation, and then how to properly express the other two options?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

1年ちょっと前 means "*a little over* a year ago", i.e., approx. 13–14 months ago. This expression is unspecific, but the speaker is not uncertain. If you are uncertain, you can say "1年ちょっとだか1年半だか前", "1年かそのくらい前", etc. 1年と少し前 is a more formal equivalent. 1年ちょい前 is more casual.

You don't have to use it with 前. Examples using similar expressions:

- [1万円ちょっとの無線LANアクセスポイント](http://businessnetwork.jp/tabid/65/artid/5880/page/2/Default.aspx)
- [ゲームを1時間ちょっとでクリア](https://youtu.be/LbO7isC5oGc?t=13m2s)

Comment: I'm trying to understand the literal meanings of 1年ちょっとだか1年半だか前" and "1年かそのくらい前".  first example: how is "だか" being used? Does it mean like "1 year OR 1 year and half ago"? Second example: How are you using "かそのくらい" is "ka" a doubting particle? is "その" meaning "that"?  "くらい" is "length of"? Soo... something like "(lit.) 1 year maybe that length of time before"? If you can, let me know the breakdown for those last two.. Thank you! Very helpful!

Comment: @Cmaxster だか is "the copula だ" followed by "the question marker か". AだかBだか forms a noun clause meaning "A or maybe B" (ex. 彼の息子だか娘だかが来た; 5人だか6人だかの集団). ～かそのくらい is "or so" or "or something like that". その is "that (in this case 1年)", くらい is "degree".

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: I was confused and answered wrongly. I apologize for this.

「一年*ちょっと*前に」 means "*a little* over a year ago"

To tell "*around* a year ago", we say "一年*くらい*前に".

To tell "**A little** over a year ago", we say "一年と**ちょっと**前に" or "一年**ちょっと**前に".

To tell "*Roughly* **a little** over a year ago", we say "一年と**ちょっと**前*くらいに*".

So to tell "I got married a little over a year ago.", we say "一年とちょっと前に結婚した".